# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '161' in

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have some javascript code that is making an ajax call when I change a dropdownlist. It just passes the selected value from the dropdown and gets a collection related to the selected value:

```
$("#ddl").change(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/MyService.asmx/GetCollection",
        data: "{'selectedId':'" + $(this).val() + "'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            $.each(response.d, function (i, item) {
                alert(item.Text);
            });
        }
    });
})
```

This works correctly, and this is the json response I'm getting from my ajax call.

```
d: 
    "[{"Id":"c709b6d3-5841-4240-b25c-9f730530a998","Text":"Item 1"},   
      {"Id":"c7dd6ee0-836a-4b19-9b88-f8f2455b6e32","Text":"Item 2"}]"
```

But when I try and loop through each item in `response.d` and alert `item.Text`, I'm getting this error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '161' in [{"Id":"c709b6d3-5841-4240-b25c-9f730530a998","Text":"Item 1"},{"Id":"c7dd6ee0-836a-4b19-9b88-f8f2455b6e32","Text":"Item 2"}]

Am I looping through this wrong? Or am I outputting the content incorrectly?

Comment: `response.d` is string, you cannot use `each` on string, parse it to JSON and then use `each` on it

Comment: @Tushar - can I do that in jQuery?

Comment: Use `var d = JSON.parse(response.d)` and then loop on `d`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like **@Tushar** mentioned in the comment you have to use a loop, for example `for` loop like following :

```
var response = {d: [{"Id":"c709b6d3-5841-4240-b25c-9f730530a998","Text":"Item 1"}, {"Id":"c7dd6ee0-836a-4b19-9b88-f8f2455b6e32","Text":"Item 2"}]};

for(var i=0;i<response.d.length;i++){
    alert(response.d[i].Text);
}
```

If the response id string use `JSON.parse` :

```
var response = JSON.parse('{"d": [{"Id":"c709b6d3-5841-4240-b25c-9f730530a998","Text":"Item 1"}, {"Id":"c7dd6ee0-836a-4b19-9b88-f8f2455b6e32","Text":"Item 2"}]}')
```

Hope this helps